# How can I compile C programs that use deprecated functions, such as gets()

Tags: c, linux, gcc

For a homework assignment, I have to try to use buffer overflows to crash a simple c program. My problem is that my compiler won't compile the `gets()` function because it is deprecated and unsafe. I understand this, but for the sake of the example, I'd like to override that.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int valid = 0;

    // Char arrays w/buffer set to 8 chars
    char str1[8];
    char str2[8];

    next_tag(str1);

    //This is where I want to use gets and not fgets or other secure functions...
    gets(str2);

    if(strncmp(str1, str2, 8) == 0) {
        valid = 1;
    }

    // Print
    printf("Buffer 1: str1(%s), str2(%s), valid(%d)\n", str1, str2, valid);


}
```

My gcc version is:

```
rabbitfighter@ECHO:[~/Code/C/BufferOverflowExamples]: gcc -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc-4.9-20140903/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-cloog-backend=isl --disable-isl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

If anyone can help me I would greatly appreciate it. I am running Manjaro Linux (Arch).

Comment: Q: What happens when you compile a module that uses "gets()"?  Do you get an error (the compile fails)?  Or do you just get a warning?  You can safely ignore the warning.

Comment: @FoggyDay: Well, you can't *safely* ignore the warning, but in this case safety isn't the point.

Comment: How exactly are you compiling the program? Please update your question and copy-and-paste the exact `gcc` command line you're using. On my system, `gcc` with no added options merely warns about (at compile time and link time) about `gets`. (The undefined reference to `next_tag` is a fatal error.)

Comment: I have tried gcc -o buffer1 buffer1.c, and  gcc -Wdeprecated-declarations -o buffer1  buffer1.c . Both don't work :)

Comment: Also, it does NOT compile. I wish it would give me a warning and continue, but it will just not compile.

Comment: Again, copy-and-paste the error you receive.

Comment: @Joshua What warning do you receive? Please share it. We can't resolve an error we don't know.

Comment: as @KeithThompson said, it's not linking because you didn't implement `next_tag()`. You can get rid of the warning (which is unrelated) with: `gcc buffer.c -o buffer -W-no-deprecated-declarations`

Comment: Both the `gcc` command you used *and* the exact error message need to be in the question, not just in a comment. "Both don't work" and "it does NOT compile" are nearly useless unless we can see the actual message you get. (If it doesn't produce a message but still doesn't create an executable, that would be very surprising, but you should tell us that in the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a "safer" funcion like fgets and give it a bogus buffer size to get unsafe behavior out of it.

A larger buffer size than the real buffer will let fgets overrun its bounds and potentially crash the program.

Just because the gun has a safety doesn't mean you can't shoot your foot off with it.

Comment: I don't think you read my question. I must use THIS CODE. I MUST use gets().

Comment: Unless you instructor is watching over your shoulder, fgets(str2, INT_MAX, stdin) should be functionally equivalent to gets in your situation. A string that crashes gets should crash fgets there (which I assume is what your instructor wants you to produce). You will need to #include limits.h to get INT_MAX.

Comment: @JoshuaMichael In your answer you don't say that you can't change the code, +1 for a possible functionally equivalent solution.
(but still think that code should compile -it does here-, I'm curious about the error)

Comment: It compiles on my Linux Mint machine, but not Arch. It's just a matter of some compilers still allow gets() with a warning, and some compilers just won't do it. Thanks to whoever down-voted my question though. Really nice when I'm just asking a question.

Comment: @JoshuaMichael Maybe they downvoted it because you didn't put the command you used and the exact warning in the question, as suggested in comments.